# GPU instancing vs combining meshes for performance

Tags: unity, c#, performance, procedural-generation

I have a relatively low poly procedurally generated scene in which I reuse a bunch of the same objects (walls, floors, etc). I've been writing some code to combine a room's floor tiles into one mesh, its wall tiles into another mesh, etc. However I came across this tutorial (http://www.habrador.com/tutorials/unity-mesh-combining-tutorial/) in which the author says that GPU instancing is essentially the same as mesh combining, but in fewer lines of code. Is this accurate? I tried GPU instancing and got a massive reduction on the GPU, but the CPU still spends a lot of time drawing. Will mesh combining provide more balanced performance for the CPU? I haven't finished my implementation yet and don't want to bother if it's effectively the same.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm... I wonder when that tutorial is from. Unity has included a feature to both statically and dynamically batch meshes together on its own, without doing it manually through C# scripting, so I wouldn't expect the manual mesh combining approach to be a big win in recent versions over what the engine does natively.

Comment: @DMGregory it looks recent - in the tutorial, the author references earlier work that had an accompanying video uploaded on Apr 19, 2017.